# Copy text as it is rendered by Emacs

Tags: copy-paste, rendering, visibility

I have Emacs doing a bunch of smart things to display text for me. In particular, some text has the `invisible` property set, and I'm running [`adaptive-wrap`](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/adaptive-wrap.html) with `<!-- adaptive-wrap-extra-indent: 3 -->` set. I'm wondering whether I can copy the text as it's rendered in Emacs, with newlines to re-create the smart line wrapping and with the invisible text gone. Is there a way I can access the text from my buffer in that form?

What I want is essentially the same as running `emacs -nw`, selecting the text using the terminal's text selection capabilities, and then using the terminal app's copy function (*not* marking using an Emacs region and then yanking). The chief problem with this technique for me is that I have to do it one screen at a time.

Running `htmlfontify-buffer` gets me part of the way there. My visible text is shown by I can make it go away by clicking on each individual instance, but the line-wrapping behavior is lost.

Answer (score 2):

Library [`subr+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/subr%2b.el) has functions that help with this. This one, for instance:

```el
(defun buffer-substring-of-visible (start end)
  "Return contents of visible part of buffer from START to END, as a string.
START and END can be in either order."
  (buffer-substring-of-unpropertied start end 'invisible))
```

Here are some others, which are similar:

- `buffer-substring-of-invisible` - Return contents of invisible part of buffer from START to END, as a string.
- `buffer-substring-of-faced` - eturn faced contents of buffer from START to END, as a string.  That is, include only text that has property `face'.
- `buffer-substring-of-unfaced` - Return unfaced contents of buffer from START to END, as a string.  That is, include only text that has no `face' property.

And the more general functions:

- `buffer-substring-of-propertied` - Return PROPERTY'ed contents of buffer from START to END, as a string. Only text from START to END that has PROPERTY is included.
- `buffer-substring-of-unpropertied` - Return unpropertied contents of buffer from START to END, as a string. Text from START to END that has PROPERTY is excluded from the string.

Comment: Nice. I'm able to throw away the invisible text with the `buffer-substring-of-visible` function you highlighted. I believe this library won't handle the line wrapping/hanging indent. Do I have that right?

Comment: Dunno; I don't know anything about `adaptive-wrap`, and don't find it in the Emacs manuals. If it uses text properties to simulate newline chars then you can use `subr+.el` to ignore those properties, but nothing there helps you replace them with newline chars. (You might want to provide a reference/link to the code that defines `adaptive-wrap`, so that others can help you with that.)

Comment: Updated the original question with link to `adaptive-wrap`. On a side note, one must at least try it out if they haven't. Wrapped lines have never looked better.