# How to copy displayed ellipsis when buffer content is folded?

Tags: copy-paste, code-folding, clipboard

I have JSON files in which I am folding away some subnodes with the  `hideshow` mode.

This works reasonably well. Now I want to create a new file or buffer with the *folded* content.

For example, my folded JSON buffer looks like:

```
{
  "type": "Helper",
  "name": "Walter",
  "skills": {...}
}
```

Then I want to copy exactly this text (with the three dots).

However, when I copy the buffer to the clipboard and paste it in another buffer, I get in the new buffer the expanded version:

```
{
  "type": "Helper",
  "name": "Walter",
  "skills": {
     "type": "list",
     "list": [ "latin", "maths" ]
  }
}
```

*How can I tell Emacs to copy the text it displays, not the text which is in the underlying buffer?*

PS: I tried [origami.el](https://github.com/gregsexton/origami.el) as well - same problem.

Comment: Related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13480/copy-text-as-it-is-rendered-by-emacs

Comment: IIUC you want to save overlays as text: perhaps https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OverlaysToText  helps?